# Storing Password in session in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Hey I am using devise to authenticate the user. But however the user requires two different form to be filled in order to get themselves registered in the app. In the first form there is username and password. The second form contains other user details.

So for that I am setting two api one for each form. The first api(POST) will validate the first form and the value is not going to be saved in the user but in the session. I want to send this data over the session to my other api so that I can use it to create and save the user.

My question is is it safe to store password in the session? Is there any other way I can implement this?

I am using two different form because the form is huge and there is a lot of logic in it. Even if I make a stepper and consider it a single form. I don't want the user to manually redirect to the first page to correct the creds. I want to throw the error in the first page if it is invalid

Comment: Can't you just create the user and mark it as `draft` or `unfinished` or something and send the id to the other form. Then when all is done uncheck it as draft.

Comment: @Eyeslandic Saving the user with just two field (username and password) will throw and error. Since there are validation in other field. I just want it to validate the two field without saving in the database

Comment: Remove the `:validatable` module and add the validations back yourself. There are plenty of guides and wiki articles for how to create a two step form in Devise and they do not involve saving the password in the session which is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: You can also have a new model called DraftUser or something with the required validations, and create an instance of that, then pass that to the second form, there are many possibilities.